# Strange task behavior in openmp under openmpi

Tags: openmp, openmpi

I have a stand with i7-5960X CPU with 8 cores + HT (16 threads). And here is a program that try to use both OpenMP and OpenMPI. It called as following:

```
# mpirun -np <NN1> -x OMP_NUM_THREADS=<NN2> <my_prog>
```

where NN1 and NN2 were varied. In the code I have this:

```
#pragma omp parallel
    nOMP=omp_get_num_threads();

    int maxOMP=omp_get_max_threads();
    int procOMP=omp_get_num_procs();
    printf("OMP version running on %d threads. Max threads=%d, available procs=%d\n", nOMP, maxOMP, procOMP);
```

Here is a result:

```
#1, NN1=2, NN2=2:
    OMP version running on 2 threads. Max threads=2, available procs=2
#2, NN1=2, NN2=4:
    OMP version running on 4 threads. Max threads=4, available procs=2
#3, NN1=3, NN2=4:
    OMP version running on 4 threads. Max threads=4, available procs=16
```

So for 1 and 2 mpi threads omp_get_num_procs() returns "2" always and for 3 and above it returns "16".

The questions are: why and how to force it to return correct value for 1 and 2 mpi threads?

OpenMpi version is 1.10.3 and GCC version is 4.8.5, Centos 7 x86_64. Direct call without mpirun is correct too.

UPD1 Here is a relevant discussion: http://forum.abinit.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=2782, but no answer anyway.

UPD2 openmpi-2.x.x fix this.

Comment: You should see as many printed lines as MPI processes. I see that you are only showing one of them. It posibly has to do with CPU binding and hyperthreading. You can manually control how the processes are bound to CPU cores using mpirun `--bind-to` options.

Comment: Thanks fore reply. Logs are go from rank #0 mpi thread only. No any binding were done here. Did I realy need them for "-np 2" while for "-np 3" it works itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default binding is
 - `NUMA domain` (e.g. socket) if  > 2
 - `core` otherwise

so if you `mpirun -np 2 ...`, there will be only one core per MPI task
but if you `mpirun -np 3 ...`, each MPI task is bound to a socket.

For example, on my VM (1 socket and 4 cores)

```
$ mpirun -np 2 grep Cpus_allowed_list /proc/self/status
Cpus_allowed_list:  0
Cpus_allowed_list:  1
$ mpirun -np 3 grep Cpus_allowed_list /proc/self/status
Cpus_allowed_list:  0-3
Cpus_allowed_list:  0-3
```

Cpus_allowed_list:  0-3

you can `mpirun -bind-to socket` or even `mpirun -bind-to none` in order to alter the default binding option.

Answer (score 0):

Some error in 1.10.x version. Openmpi-2.x.x fix this.